# Flask-JWT-Extended - Bad Authorization Header

Tags: flask, jwt

I'm using the following code to test out Flask JWT.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_jwt_extended import (
    JWTManager, jwt_required, create_access_token,
    get_jwt_identity
)

app = Flask(__name__)

# Setup the Flask-JWT-Extended extension
app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = 'super-secret'  # Change this!
jwt = JWTManager(app)


# Provide a method to create access tokens. The create_access_token()
# function is used to actually generate the token, and you can return
# it to the caller however you choose.
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    if not request.is_json:
        return jsonify({"msg": "Missing JSON in request"}), 400

    username = request.json.get('username', None)
    password = request.json.get('password', None)
    if not username:
        return jsonify({"msg": "Missing username parameter"}), 400
    if not password:
        return jsonify({"msg": "Missing password parameter"}), 400

    if username != 'test' or password != 'test':
        return jsonify({"msg": "Bad username or password"}), 401

    # Identity can be any data that is json serializable
    access_token = create_access_token(identity=username)
    return jsonify(access_token=access_token), 200


# Protect a view with jwt_required, which requires a valid access token
# in the request to access.
@app.route('/protected', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required
def protected():
    # Access the identity of the current user with get_jwt_identity
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    return jsonify(logged_in_as=current_user), 200


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

By using POSTMAN, I am able to get the following access_token

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1ODkxMTg0MTcsIm5iZiI6MTU4OTExODQxNywianRpIjoiNDEwNzFlZjItZTE3OC00YzhkLThjN2ItNWIwN2MxNGNkYzI2IiwiZXhwIjoxNTg5MTE5MzE3LCJpZGVudGl0eSI6InRlc3QiLCJmcmVzaCI6ZmFsc2UsInR5cGUiOiJhY2Nlc3MifQ.A1C1vMXnXt4IWO8j4H4LH6caxCqBg19lOEoVHhYnIyU"
}
```

But when I want to access the /protected page using GET with the Header

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1ODkxMTg0MTcsIm5iZiI6MTU4OTExODQxNywianRpIjoiNDEwNzFlZjItZTE3OC00YzhkLThjN2ItNWIwN2MxNGNkYzI2IiwiZXhwIjoxNTg5MTE5MzE3LCJpZGVudGl0eSI6InRlc3QiLCJmcmVzaCI6ZmFsc2UsInR5cGUiOiJhY2Nlc3MifQ.A1C1vMXnXt4IWO8j4H4LH6caxCqBg19lOEoVHhYnIyU
```

I get this error in POSTMAN. Any recommendation on how to fix the issue will be very much appreciated.

```
{
    "msg": "Bad Authorization header. Expected value 'Bearer <JWT>'"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Found the answer. Been having the problem for few days. The solution is that in POSTMAN, you don't add the

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1ODkxMTg0MTcsIm5iZiI6MTU4OTExODQxNywianRpIjoiNDEwNzFlZjItZTE3OC00YzhkLThjN2ItNWIwN2MxNGNkYzI2IiwiZXhwIjoxNTg5MTE5MzE3LCJpZGVudGl0eSI6InRlc3QiLCJmcmVzaCI6ZmFsc2UsInR5cGUiOiJhY2Nlc3MifQ.A1C1vMXnXt4IWO8j4H4LH6caxCqBg19lOEoVHhYnIyU
```

into the header. You need to go into the Authorization tab in POSTMAN, Select Bearer and enter the token in the field. This is how to add the token as a bearer token. This will resolve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error while making api call from Angular app :

where **Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1 ......**

Here is the another approach to add auth token

```
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor{ 
constructor(private injector: Injector ) { }
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
   let authService = this.injector.get(AuthService);
   let tokenizeReq = req.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${authService.getAccessToken()}`
    }
   });
  return next.handle(tokenizeReq);
 }
}
```

Where authService.getAccessToken will return the token.
This will add token to http calls

Don't forget to add interceptor in
app.modules

```
providers: [{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: TokenInterceptorService,
  multi: true
}]
```